# Intellij constantly compiles TypeScript (very slow) - How to stop this behavior?

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, typescript, gulp

I am in the process of migrating an Angular 1.x project from vanilla JS to TypeScript. However, I am experiencing extremely slow response times from my IDE.[image: Constant compiling of many files]

If I uncheck "Track changes" in Settings > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript, the compilation stops--but I am then in a position where my TS doesn't compile!

Of course, I could configure a gulp file and set a watcher that recompiles files on change. But, if possible, I would like to avoid the need to run gulp for each project. Also, *more importantly*, unchecking "Track changes" removes TS specific advice AND appears to break some references.

Track changes: Checked - *Help + references*
[image: Help + References]

Track changes: Unchecked - *No help + References broken*
[image: No help + References broken]

Question #1:

**Is it possible to configure Intellij such that it only compiles changed files?**

Question #2:

**Why is Intellij compiling *so many* files?**
Here is a copy of my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outFile": "build/local/tsc.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./typings"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },

  "exclude": [
    "client/src/node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/bower_components",
    "client/src/bower_components",
    "client/src/node_modules",
    "build",
    "Saved_HTML",
    "site-ideas",
    "node_modules",
    "client/typings"
  ]
}
```

Note that despite setting node_modules as an ignored directory, the compiler is still reaching in there. [image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

IntelliJ saves files pretty frequently. Typescript compiles when a file is saved. Therfore, you should [disable or limit autosave](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207054215-Disabling-autosave).

**Question 2:**

I dont know why excluding files doesn't work for you, but I suggest rather to include `"rootDir": "./yourSourceDir"` than exclude other files.